# Android getLatitude() on geopoint returns null when i have more than 1 document in cloud store

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Cause of Error is document `getGeoPoint("geopoint")` `getLongitude()` and 
 `getLatitude()`. Errors only occur when pulling more than 1 document. If I comment Longitude and Latitude out all documents load perfectly in my recylerview

```
    db.collection(COLLECTION_TAG)
            .whereEqualTo("active", true)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            ServiceName = document.getString("service_name");
                            gsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://service-elf.appspot.com/"+ServiceName+".jpg");
                            StreetAddress = document.getString("address");
                            Website = document.getString("website");
                            ContactNumber = document.getString("contact");
                            Longitude = document.getGeoPoint("geopoint").getLongitude(); 
                            Latitude = document.getGeoPoint("geopoint").getLatitude();


                            String shours = ""+document.get("service_hours");
                            shours = shours.substring(1,shours.length()-1);
                            String[] hours = shours.split(",");
                            Hours = hours[getDay()];


                            Log.d("MainAct", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData() + shours + url);
                            services.add(new cService(url,ServiceName,StreetAddress,Website,ContactNumber,-30.111,18.111,Hours)}
```

Error null pointer exception

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: za.co.sedi.serviceapp, PID: 14753
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
                  at za.co.sedi.serviceapp.MainActivity$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:112)
                  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Data in document from Log

```
2ig2nIDo5QPxS1AkFT8F => {address=21 some road , cape town, western cape,   service_name=alpha,contact=098765432,area=Ottery,active=true,website=www.alpha.com,service_hours=[7:00am - 6:00pm, 7:00am - 6:00pm, 7:00am - >6:00pm, 7:00am - 6:00pm, 7:00am - 6:00pm, 10:00am - 4:00pm, 12:00pm - 3:00pm],geopoint=GeoPoint { latitude=18.501747, longitude=-34.013823 }}
```

Data Structure using firebase database cloud firestore
link to data structure https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wQjV96dd_LuPr1pfupuQrR7Mv5O2pnpR

cService Class

```
public class cService {
    private String Img;
    private String Name;
    private String StreetAddress;
    private String website;
    private String ContactNumber;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private String Hours;

    public cService(){

    }

    public  cService(String Img, String Name, String StreetAddress, String website, String ContactNumber, double longitude, double latitude, String hours){
        this.Img = Img;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.StreetAddress = StreetAddress;
        this.website = website;
        this.ContactNumber = ContactNumber;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.Hours = hours;
    }
    //gets
    public String getImg(){
        return Img;
    }

    public String getcName(){
        return Name;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress(){
        return StreetAddress;
    }

    public String getWebsite(){
        return website;
    }

    public String getContactNumber(){
        return ContactNumber;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getHours(){
        return Hours;
    }

    //sets
    public void setImg(String Img){
        this.Img = Img;
    }

    public void setcName(String Name){
        this.Name =  Name;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String StreetAddress){
        this.StreetAddress = StreetAddress;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website){
        this.website = website;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String ContactNumber){
        this.ContactNumber = ContactNumber;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude){
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours){
        this.Hours = hours;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can log all the document each time and post it here.

Comment: It's not that _"getLatitude() on geopoint returns null"_, but the `GeoPoint` itself is `null`. (According to the attached error log at least.)

Comment: yeah i know that it says GeoPoint itself is null but I'm not sure why because there is a GeoPoint in the document data. I'm thinking maybe there is a bug in Firebases getGeoPoint() that occurs when getting all documents in a collection?

Comment: @Pyro Please add your database structure and the class that holds those fields.

Comment: @AlexMamo the data structure is at the bottom its a cloud firestore db there is no internal db and im not using the geopoint data yet im just trying to pull it with the rest of my data

Comment: @Pyro Please add a screnshot of your actual database.

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry my rep isn't high enough to add pictures XD

Comment: @AlexMamo lol got the work around

Comment: add null checks before reading the data. Usually in testing when rules are not added data can be null and so the exception will appear. Having null checks helps graceful handling in app if data is corrupt.

Comment: @Pyro So you basically say that if you have only one document it work correctly and if you more then one you get that error, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yip you got it

Comment: "If I comment Longitude and Latitude out all documents load perfectly in my recylerview" even if you have more than 1 document?

Comment: Yeah I've basically just continued coding without those variables and everything works however i do need to get that data X_X I'm thinking maybe its a bug with firestore code since they are still in beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Firebase support I found out that the problem was occurring because of a broken document in the firestore database (Broken documents can be identified by fields not being in alphabetical order).

Resolved the problem by recreating the document and deactivating the broken document by setting active to false stopping it showing up when I query the collection with

```
db.collection(COLLECTION_TAG).whereEqualTo("active", true).get()...
```